# Nhibernate date comparison

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve. I want to pass a date, then retrieve all itemorders that were picked on that date using NHibernate.

When I pass a orderPickDate to the method below, it never comes back with a result. I don't want to pass a date range, I just want to pass a single date, ignore the time, and if any itemOrders exist with that pick date return them.

```
public IList<ItemOrder> GetItemOrderByCriteria(int? itemNumber, int? warehouseNumber, DateTime? orderPickDate)
    {
        try
        {
            NHibernate.ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Core.ItemOrder));

            if (itemNumber.HasValue)
                criteria.CreateCriteria("Item", "Item").Add(Expression.Eq("Item.ItemNumber", itemNumber.Value));


            if (warehouseNumber.HasValue)
                criteria.CreateCriteria("Warehouse", "Warehouse").Add(Expression.Eq("Warehouse.WarehouseNumber", warehouseNumber));

            if (orderPickDate.HasValue)
                criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("OrdPickDate", orderPickDate));

            return criteria.List<Core.ItemOrder>();
        }
        catch (NHibernate.HibernateException he)
        {
            DataAccessException dae = new DataAccessException("NHibernate Exception", he);
            throw dae;
        }

    }
```

Here's how this column is set up in the mapping:

```
<property name="OrdPickDate" column="ORD_PICK_DATE" type="date" not-null="true"/>
```

When I look at the sql nhibernate creates, it adds the following where clause(I passed it 12/1/2009 12:00:00 AM):

```
WHERE  this_.ORD_PICK_DATE = '2009-12-01T00:00:00.00'
```

If I try to run the query in a db editor I get an error saying "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string." Should I be taking a different approach in creating my criteria?

Comment: did you try to find the right expression in the SQLPLUS (db-editor) ?
if the column stores exact dates, you will need to use a function to clear the times...

Comment: I could make sure all records saved by the application have no time, but if a date were to be modified beyond the application then I wouldn't be able to retrieve it. I need a way for nhibernate to ignore the time since nhibernate is generating the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem you are describing comes from the fact that in Oracle a DATE type is a point in time. It always has the time component, even if sometimes it is not displayed (the time component is hidden).

To perform a date search you would either:

1. compare with a range of date (`WHERE dt BETWEEN :d1 AND :d2` *or* `WHERE dt >= :d1 AND dt <= :d2`)
2. compare the "day" portion of the date (for example `WHERE trunc(dt) = :d1`)
3. store only the date portion in your column (i-e for all rows `trunc(dt)=dt` or in other words all rows are at "12:00AM"), preferably enforced by a column constraint. The `WHERE dt = :d1` in that case would work.

In all tree cases you would put a date type at both sides of the operand. I suppose Hibernate naturally uses the right datatype when you specify "DATE". In SQL*Plus, you would explicitely use the right datatype with a `to_date` function:

```
WHERE  this_.ORD_PICK_DATE = to_date('2009-12-01 00:00:00', 
                                     'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss')
```

To adress performance issues: case (1) and (3) will be able to use regular indexes on the column whereas case (2) will not.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your input, I changed my code to the following and it's now working:

if (orderPickDate.HasValue)
                {
                    DateTime minPickDate = new DateTime(orderPickDate.Value.Year, orderPickDate.Value.Month, orderPickDate.Value.Day, 0,0,0);
                    DateTime maxPickDate = new DateTime(orderPickDate.Value.Year, orderPickDate.Value.Month, orderPickDate.Value.Day, 23,59,59);

                    criteria.Add(Expression.Between("OrdPickDate", minPickDate, maxPickDate));
                }